# Script doesn't load in the following condition

Tags: jquery, ajax, if-statement, display

I want to load a **script** only after the user logged in to the app and a certain **page** is **visible**. I set the page to **display block** in my **ajax**, and after that I say if the page is set to display block get the script but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Login POST 
$('#frm-login').submit(function (e) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $loginButton.text('Please wait ...').prop('disabled')
    $.ajax({
        url: "/login-user",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#frm-login').serialize(),
        dataType: "json"
    }).always(function (response) {
        $loginButton.text('Logging in').prop('disabled')
        console.log("Login", response)
        if (response.status == "error") {
            $loginButton.removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
            return
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.token)
        if (sessionStorage.token) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/verify-user",
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.token
                },
                dataType: "json"
            }).always(function (response) {
                console.log("Auth", response)
                if (response.status == "error") {
                    $loginButton.removeClass('lime').addClass('red').text('Log in failed. Try again.');
                    return
                }
                $('#index-page').css('display', 'none')
                $('#main-page').css('display', 'block')
            })
        }
    })
})

// add scripts to #main-page

if ($('#main-page').css('display') == 'block') {
    $.getScript('</script><script src="/js/socket.js"></script>')
    console.log("JS loaded")
}
```

my html is basically wrapped into this 2 divs.

```
<body>
    <div id="index-page">

    </div>
    <div id="main-page">

    </div>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should use `sessionStorage.getItem('token')` instead of `sessionStorage.token`

Comment: Show us your HTML.

Comment: Where are you "say[ing] if the page is set to display block get the script"? I have no idea what that's supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a few things going on. You check `#main-page` for block display only once, when the script is initially run, not when it changes from the login and verification. Secondly, the syntax for `$.getScript()` is `$.getScript(url, success)` (see: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

I'd move the script loading code after the verification, like so:

```
            // ...
            $('#index-page').css('display', 'none')
            $('#main-page').css('display', 'block')
            // moved code
            $.getScript('/js/socket.js', function () {
                console.log('script loaded');
            });
```

Comment: i see.  is there no other option? I feel like I am doing everything under this submit event and is getting huge. is it good practice to write code like this in jquery? I haven't worked with it much.

Comment: Generally you should break up your code into smaller functions, e.g. a login handler, then a verification handler. But this sort of problem was common a few years ago, where a lot of callbacks were chained together creating what was called  **callback hell**. It's been alleviated somewhat with promises.